# SML: If -> is right associative

Tags: functional-programming, sml

Ullman's book, *Elements of ML Programming*, introduces a simple version of the map function defined as follows:

```
fun simpleMap(F, nil) = nil
|   simpleMap(F, x::xs) = F(x)::simpleMap(F, xs);

val map = fn : ('a -> 'b) * 'a list -> 'b list
```

Given that -> is right associative, wouldn't you parenthesize like this:

```
('a -> 'b) * ('a list -> 'b list) ?
```

But this is incorrect since the domain type is a tuple consisting of the function and a list and the range type is just a list.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `->` isn't the only type operator in that signature..? There's another one in between the two arrows, so their *associativity* isn't what's important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SML, the type operator `*` binds more tightly than `->`: it has a higher precedence just like `*` has a higher precedence than `+` in arithmetic.

This is why `string * string -> string` is the same as `(string * string) -> string` and not `string * (string -> string)`. To read your example, we'd need to put parentheses around the `*` before worrying about how `->` associates:

```
(('a -> 'b) * 'a list) -> 'b list
```